# Delete a task stored in SQL database through html form using Python

Tags: python, html, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

This is a web app written in `Python` to add and delete tasks.

This is the **add_tasks** function:

```
@app.route("/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def add():
    
    if request.method == "POST":                
        add = request.form.get("add")
        quantity = request.form.get("quantity")
        if not add:
            return apology("Please add an item")      
        
        db.execute("INSERT INTO history (add, quantity, user_id) VALUES (:add, :quantity, :user_id);", add=add, quantity=quantity, user_id=session["user_id"])

        return redirect("/")

    else:
        return render_template("add.html")
```

Then my **delete** function takes only the stored items from `SQL` database to `SELECT`, in order to erase them.

```
@app.route("/delete", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def delete():

    if request.method == "POST":
        db.execute("DELETE FROM history (add, quantity, user_id) VALUES (:add, :quantity, :user_id);", add=add, quantity=0, user_id=session["user_id"])

    else:
        rows = db.execute("SELECT add FROM history WHERE user_id=:user_id GROUP BY add",
                    user_id=session["user_id"])
        return render_template("delete.html", add=[row["add"] for row in rows])
```

This delete function leads to an **internal server error**. What´s wrong about it?

Comment: If you want to be restful, the endpoint should be the same but one with `POST` method, the other with `DELETE`

Comment: I know, thanks, I tried to make it similar but I couldn´t make it work (beginners issues)

Comment: Well, you should have a look at SQL DELETE statement: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp :)

Comment: Thanks, @RobinFrcd. I´ll take a look and keep trying. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the `POST` part of my `DELETE` function was wrong. I´ve managed to find this solution:

```
db.execute("DELETE FROM history WHERE user_id=:user_id and add=:add;", user_id=session["user_id"], add=add)
```

Thanks, [RobinFrcd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5692012/robinfrcd) for your help!